# Does rsync --files-from work with an rsync daemon?

Tags: rsync

I've used --files-from over ssh, but I'm unable to make this option work with an rsync daemon. Here's what I'm trying:

`echo refseq/H_sapiens/README | rsync -HRav --files-from=- ftp.ncbi.nih.gov:: 2015-04-28/`

I get a list of files as though I hadn't provided any files to sync, which makes me think that rsync ignores --files-from with daemons.

Despite the hostname with ftp, the site does support rsync. This does work:

`rsync -HRav ftp.ncbi.nih.gov::refseq/H_sapiens/README 2015-04-28/`

Anyone tried this before?